# Unable to edit form using DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

puu.sh/kiQ0k/aa28192731.png

Does anyone know how I can manipulate the objects in this form? I would really like to be able to edit some of the tabs. It's using DevExpress v14.1

Comment: Please insert some code of your grid definition so that people can have idea and guide you where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To edit the tabs, just click the tab control and use the design time helper icon on the tab controls upper right corner. There, you can find a link called "Tab pages".

[image]

Alternatively you can just select the tab control by clicking and head over to the properties window (press F4) as you can do with every control. There, you find a property called `TabPages`.

If you want to edit the **controls on the tabs**, just do so by selecting them per mouse click and change the controls' properties on the properties window (press F4).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that DevExpress wasn't installed on my system and thus wouldn't let me modify the elements. Simply installing the right version fixed the issue.